# How do you make RSS feeds work under IIS 7?

Tags: rss, iis

Running IIS 7 and WP 3.0.

I've got a web.config that has the necessary rewrite rules to make permalinks work, and they're working.

However, if I point to n-nexus.realtimepublishers.com/content/?feed=rss2, the server first generates an HTTP 404. Weirdly, it then delivers the RSS feed. The problem is that the initial 404 makes things like FeedBurner and Safari barf; Firefox displays the feed properly (you can see the 404 error in Live HTTP Headers, though).

What the heck am I not configuring properly?

UPDATE: Disabled all plugins. No change. Boo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 404 is typical of WP thinking it has got no posts. Seeing that you actually have posts, I'm prompted to ask if you've plugins that mess around with query arguments or that override the loop partially or entirely? If so, they might be missing a few lines of code to allow WP to "know" it has found posts.

Comment: I dunno. It does return posts in the feed. Will try shutting everything off though, but not holding breath.

Comment: Yeah, killed every plugin - no change. :(

Comment: Ok - so you're right - sorta. I have a WP database that contains numerous posts of custom types, but none of the 'post' type. I modified the RSS/RSS2/RDF/ATOM feed PHP files to change the WP query to include "post_type=any" which includes the custom post types in the RSS feed. However, if you don't have at least one post, however old, of type "post," then WP generates a 404 error when you hit the feed. So I've added an old "post" and it's working. This seems like it's gotta be a bug of some kind in WP's custom post typed code, yes?